# Importing google app engine project from eclipse into intellij

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm trying out intellij to see what it is like to develop/maintain google app engine projects.  I've used the GAE plugin for eclipse for a couple of years and it usually worked flawlessly for me but I've heard a lot about intellij recently so I wanted to see what I was missing.

I've read many sites that describe step-by-step how to create new GAE projects in intellij but none that describe how to do so for existing projects.  I'm struggling with I imagine is some intellij 101 topics.  I have a few questions that I'm bundling together here:

1. I added the Web/GAE facet to the project and specified the appropriate GAE SDK directory and appengine account info.  What's the right way to associate the right SDK jars with my project?
2. IntelliJ recognized my maven imports and added them to my External Libraries, things like apache commons, slf4j, etc.  How do these jars make their way into the (exploded war) artifact I created for the project?  Are they automatically copied there after a successful compile?
3. I'm using JDO so I downloaded the DataNucleus plugin.  How do I wire it up so it enhances my classes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. File - Project Structure - Modules - AppEngine: at the right side is "Path to AppEngine SDK install directory". Click button right to it to select dir via file selector. This is the right way - here Intellij will use all the needed jars in your project, no need to add GAE jars by hand .
2. File - Project Structure - Artifacts: you should have a war artifact here. Create one if it's not there (+). Jars used in the project should be in "Available Elements" pane. You can add jars (if not added automatically) by drag-n-dropping them between panes. Yes, jars will be copied into war if they are in the left pane showing the contents of the package.
3. File - Project Structure - Modules - AppEngine: check the "Run enhancer for the following classes.." and select your classes/packages.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I've tried those already and while #1 & #3 seem easy, I think my problems lie in #2. All I see in the available elements pane on the right is 2 available elements: "appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1 (project library)" and "Web facet resources".  I see an error highlighted in a red box on that same screen that states that for this artifact, library "appengine-java-ask-1.6.1" required is missing from the artifact.  When I drag it over to the WEB-INF/lib, it places it there as a dir; doesn't seem right to me.  I still see a compile error in my code that it can't resolve symbol appengine.

Comment: screenshot of artifact config: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7075471/Screenshot%20at%202012-09-12%2007%3A32%3A51.png

Comment: You definitely need to add "Web facet resources" (this are all html + js files in webapp dir) to the artifact. I also have GAE jars in lib dir, but not as directory.

Comment: Did you add all those jars by hand or were they automatically sucked in?  I can do this by hand as well but I was hoping I wouldn't have to .

Comment: I created a new project and when I went to add the appengine library dependency in the module configuration, it automatically included the correct jars.  Marking this question as answered although I'm still working through some problems.  Thanks Peter.

Comment: Just post the questions, we'll try to help a fellow IDEAer.

Comment: IDEA really works well with maven. I suggest using it. It automatically resolves maven deps and includes it in IDEA project.

Comment: Thanks for the support Peter.  I got it figured out.  What it came down to is that intellij (and I) struggled with how my project was  organized so the mercurial import left things misconfigured.  I didn't know intellij well enough to know what needed to go where.  I created a new GAE project, saw how intellij expects everything, and moved my imported config towards that.  I finally got it working tonight.